# Show an svg in a force graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I have a force graph with nodes and links and I want to represent the batterystatus as a svg over each node. My problem is that I do not know how to create the image an place it over my node.

Fiddle Link http://fiddle.jshell.net/angelov/gt2j14g6/15/

This is how my **JS code** looks, but it does not represent anything over the nodes:

```
function updateBatteryNotification(value) {
batteryIndicator = document.querySelector("#indicator");
batteryIndicator.style.width = value + "%";}

updateBatteryNotification(20);

var newElement = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'batteryBody');

var batt = document.getElementById('batteryBody');

node.append("svg:svg")
    .attr("x", -15)
    .attr("y", -42)
    .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { 
    return newElement;
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
<div id="batteryBody">
    <div id="indicator"> </div>
</div>
<div class="batteryEnd"><div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#batteryBody {
float: left;
width: 30px;
height: 11px;
border: 2px #CCC solid;
}
.container {
width: 40px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 5px;
}
.batteryEnd {
float: left;
height: 12px;
width: 3px;
}
.batteryEnd div {
width: 2px;
height: 5px;
margin-top: 5px;
margin-left: 2px;
background-color: #CCC;
}
#indicator {
height: 100%;
width: 50%;
}
#indicator.charging {
background-color: #BFFF00;
}
#indicator.notCharging {
background-color: #FFFF00;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide jsFiddle containing your code?

Comment: if I'm reading your question correctly, what you actually want to know is "how do I add an image in my SVG code". That question is answered millions of times both on google and stackoverflow itself.

Comment: And I can not do it, so either help or do not spam